# Can you duck through a door that has to be pulled open?

Tags: expressions

> She ducked through the nearest door.

Would you say it's only possible to duck through a door that has to be pushed or could I also use "duck through" if the door had to be pulled open?

Comment: I don't think it's remotely relevant whether a door you "ducked through" needed to be pushed or pulled (further) open to allow you to get through. To be honest, I don't see any reason why you can't duck through even a really *high* door (that doesn't require you to stoop / duck your head). But this is really just personal stylistic choices.

Comment: ...note that you can [***duck through an alley***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ducked+through+an+alley%22), with no implication that you had to push or pull anything out of the way, and/or bow your head, etc.

Comment: I would not write that someone ducked, passed, ran, or moved through a door, since doors are solid and not easily penetrated by human beings. A door**way**, now that's different.

Comment: You can't duck a question until it has been opened.

Comment: Maybe the nearest door had a pet door? And who is "she"?

Comment: A door is a solid thing. You can duck through a **doorway**, as long as the door is open. If it is closed, you would have to open it.

Comment: You can **[duck²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/duck) or [grouse²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grouse)** right [*here*](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-nursery-plant-shop-with-low-doorway-and-sign-over-saying-duck-or-grouse-50523789.html)

Answer (score 1):

You duck *under* things.

*Duck* can also mean a quick lowering of the head or whole body, which you might do to avoid making eye contact as you are trying to avoid or leave a social situation you don't want to be in.

You can say *duck through* if you are making the motion of lowering your whole body while you are going through a door, or something like a low door or opening.  This is not a typical situation.

> She heard someone in the hallway and ducked through the nearest door.

The picture I have in my mind with this sentence is that the door is three or four feet tall and you have to be ducking to move through it.