# Can you duck through a door?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I have asked this before on two different forums, but there seems to be different opinions on this, so I'll just ask again. Can you duck through a door? Or can you only duck into a room?

She heard someone in the hallway and ducked through the nearest door.

Comment: Please don’t ask again. Instead, merge your accounts and edit your existing question (https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/243756/41273).